# Multi-Channel Contacts Problem: Find related tickets based on their information

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, relationship, kaggle

#### Problem Description

The following problem description was taken from the Shopee Code League 2021.

For each ticket, identify all contacts from each user if they have the same contact information. Each of these tickets is related either directly or indirectly through `Email`, `Phone` or `Order ID`, therefore each ticket belongs to the same user. For example:

| Ticket | ID | Email | Order ID | Phone | Contacts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | 0 | john@gmail.com | 12345678 | NA | 5 |
| **B** | 1 | NA | 12345678 | 682212345 | 2 |
| **C** | 34567 | wick@gmail.com | NA | 682212345 | 4 |
| **D** | 78999 | wick@gmail.com | NA | NA | 3 |

- Ticket A and B are linked through `Order ID`
- Tickets B and C are linked through `Phone`
- Tickets C and D are linked through `Email`
- Tickets A and D are **indirectly linked** through tickets `A` > `B` > `C` > `D`

In this example, this user has a total of 14 `Contact`. The ticket_trace/contact pair for this user would be `0-1-34567-78999, 14`.

For each ticket, identify all other `ID` that belong to the same user, sorted in ascending order, as well as the total `Contact` the user had. Generate a `csv` file with 2 columns in the below format:

| ID | ticket_trace and Contact |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0-1-34567-78999, 14 |
| 1 | 0-1-34567-78999, 14 |
| ⋮ | ⋮ |

Note that there are 500,000 rows of data. What is the most efficient way of solving this problem in a **short time** with the **least time complexity** and **memory usage**?

#### Problem Dataset

Sample of input file, `contacts.json`:

```json
[
   {
      "Id":0,
      "Email":"gkzAbIy@qq.com",
      "Phone":"",
      "Contacts":1,
      "OrderId":""
   },
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Email":"",
      "Phone":"329442681752",
      "Contacts":4,
      "OrderId":"vDDJJcxfLtSfkooPhbYnJdxov"
   }, // more data
]
```

[Click here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f5Dc9yhOn6awThmAIGxaGZCYvPLzKW51) for the problem dataset and more detailed description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution using Python3. I used 2 dictionaries to store ticket connections. The first dictionary stores connected tickets by value. Second dictionary stores each id connection (trace). Finally, calculate contacts using trace from the second dictionary. Yeah, also a very slow way. It requires 3 loops. It takes up to 15 seconds to calculate all 500.000 rows in Kaggle kernel.

[Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/yeogaa/multi-channel-contacts-0-953-15-sec)

```py
# Import tools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Load data
df = pd.read_json('/kaggle/input/scl-2021-da/contacts.json')
npdata = df.values

# Initialize memory
memory = {}
connections = {}

# Store connected tickets by value
def add_to_memory(ticket_id, value):
    if value != "":
        if value in memory:
            memory[value].add(ticket_id)
            return
        memory[value] = {ticket_id}

for row in npdata:
    ticket_id = row[0]

    # Order Id
    add_to_memory(ticket_id, row[4])

    # Email
    add_to_memory(ticket_id, row[1])

    # Phone
    add_to_memory(ticket_id, row[2])

# Calculate Trace
for ids in memory.values():
    current_connection = set(ids)

    for uid in ids:
        if uid in connections:
            current_connection.update(connections[uid])

    for uid in current_connection:
        connections[uid] = current_connection

# Calculate contacts and add to list
output = []
for ticket_id, trace in sorted(connections.items()):
    contacts = np.sum(npdata[list(trace), 3])
    trace = "-".join([str(_id) for _id in sorted(trace)])
    answer = "{}, {}".format(trace, contacts)
    output.append({"ticket_id": ticket_id,  "ticket_trace/contact": answer})

# Convert to pandas DataFrame & save to csv
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output)
filename = "output.csv"
output_df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

[Reference](https://articlearn.id/vngla21/articles/9b7ff55c-shopee-code-league-2021-multi-channel-con/)

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempted solution. I didn't have enough time to process all 500,000 rows though. Basically, I iterate through the array of data and compare their attributes in sequence. Yeah, a very slow way.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Ticket[] tickets = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("contacts.json"), Ticket[].class);

        HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> ticketTraceMap = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> sumOfContactsMap = new HashMap<>();
        int commonId = 1; // tickets with same commonId's are related

        for (int i = 0; i < tickets.length; ++i) {
            // assign new commonId and increment it if a particular ticket
            // is not related to other tickets yet
            if (tickets[i].commonId == 0) {
                tickets[i].commonId = commonId;
                ++commonId;
            }
            
            int sumOfContacts = 0;
            LinkedList<Integer> ticketTraceList = new LinkedList<>();
            ticketTraceList.add(Integer.parseInt(tickets[i].getId()));

            // get sum of contacts and ticket trace if present
            if (sumOfContactsMap.get(tickets[i].commonId) != null) {
                sumOfContacts = sumOfContactsMap.get(tickets[i].commonId);
            }

            if (ticketTraceMap.get((tickets[i].commonId)) != null) {
                ticketTraceList = ticketTraceMap.get((tickets[i].commonId));
            }

            for (int j = i + 1; j < tickets.length; ++j) {
                if (tickets[i].equals(tickets[j])) {
                    tickets[j].commonId = tickets[i].commonId; // assign commonId to link related tickets
                    sumOfContacts += Integer.parseInt(tickets[j].getContacts());
                    ticketTraceList.add(Integer.parseInt(tickets[j].getId()));
                }
            }
            ticketTraceMap.put(tickets[i].commonId, ticketTraceList);
            sumOfContactsMap.put(tickets[i].commonId, sumOfContacts);
        }
        // store ticket trace string
        HashMap<Integer, String> ticketTraceStringMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : ticketTraceMap.entrySet()) {
            Collections.sort(entry.getValue()); // sort ticket trace in ascending order
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // concatenate ticket trace into a string
            for (Integer integer : entry.getValue()) {
                sb.append(integer).append("-");
            }
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
            ticketTraceStringMap.put(entry.getKey(), sb.toString());
        }
        // print result to a csv file
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("result.csv");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String columnNamesList = "ticket_id,ticket_trace/contact\n";
        builder.append(columnNamesList);

        for (int i = 0; i < tickets.length; ++i) {
            builder.append(tickets[i].getId()).append(",").append("\"").
                    append(ticketTraceStringMap.get(tickets[i].commonId)).append(", ").
                    append(sumOfContactsMap.get((tickets[i].commonId))).append("\"").
                    append('\n');
            pw.write(builder.toString());
            builder.setLength(0);
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Java object for storing ticket information:

```java
class Ticket {
    private String Id;
    private String Email;
    private String Phone;
    private String OrderId;
    private String Contacts;
    public int commonId;

    // compare 2 tickets based on email, phone no. and order ID
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Ticket ticket = (Ticket) o;
        return (!getEmail().equals("") && Objects.equals(getEmail(), ticket.getEmail())) ||
                (!getPhone().equals("") && Objects.equals(getPhone(), ticket.getPhone())) ||
                (!getOrderId().equals("") && Objects.equals(getOrderId(), ticket.getOrderId()));
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```